# Is there a way to improve voice to text results?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, voice-recognition

Lately, I've been doing quite a bit of dictation using the voice-to-text functionality.  For the most part, it's all right but it's developed some annoying behavior.

1. Regular words are getting replaced with proper nouns.  "My Key" becomes "Mikey" even with a decent pause between the words.  "Two Chains" becomes "2 Chainz"
2. Words are getting shortened "cause" often becomes "cuz".

Are there settings to make the voice-to-text NOT change what I actually said? I do see it type out "My Key" and change it into "Mikey"

I have my language set to US English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Gboard, there's indeed currently no option to correct a word so that you can improve the speech to text recognition.

See https://android.stackexchange.com/a/244527/12202  for a mediocre workaround.