# How do I add new text to speech entries using Gboard?

Tags: voice-recognition, gboard

I was using SwiftKey prior to this but I switched over to Gboard because it has better voice recognition when using speech to text. Something got changed in SwiftKey recently and the quality of speech-to-text went down significantly. But with SwiftKey I was able to correct words that I dictated and I thought that that improved the speech-to-text algorithms.

With Gboard there's no option to correct a word so I can't improve the speech to text recognition. Does this option exist and I can't find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Gboard, there's indeed currently no option to correct a word so that you can improve the speech to text recognition.

The  closest option is to add  some entry in the Gboard personal dictionary (screenshots from Androidd 12 + Pixel 6), thanks [user1874594](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/92782/user1874594) for [showing me](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/243092/12202) this trick:

[image]

[image]

Then you'll see the fixed word as a suggestion (only after the voice typing stopped being active):

[image]

Comment: long time with no answers so this one wins by default :) I'm on Android 12 now so I don't know if the question is applicable to my current setup.

Comment: @jcollum by default, my favorite way to win! https://youtu.be/BXHyFETXPc0